# Using steps of MKRoute to create a light version of turn by turn navigation

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I am using MKRoute to get the steps between a star and a destination point on a MkMapView.

Now I don't get the gps positions from the points where the user should turn left or right. Is it possible to get these gps positions? With these positions, it should be possible to show the user a hint if it's time to turn left or right.

Thanks

I am using swift on iOS 8.